# Why Does A Unit Test For destroy_all fail with let?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

So I have this model code:

```
def self.cleanup
    Transaction.where("created_at < ?", 30.days.ago).destroy_all
  end
```

and this rspec unit test:

```
describe 'self.cleanup' do
    before(:each) do
      @transaction = Transaction.create(seller:item.user, buyer:user, item:item, created_at:6.weeks.ago)
    end

    it 'destroys all transactions more than 30 days' do
      Transaction.cleanup
      expect(@transaction).not_to exist_in_database
    end
  end
```

with these factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :transaction do
    association :seller, factory: :user, username: 'IAMSeller'
    association :buyer, factory: :user, username: 'IAmBuyer'
    association :item
  end

  factory :old_transaction, parent: :transaction do
    created_at 6.weeks.ago
  end
end
```

using this rspec custom matcher:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :exist_in_database do
  match do |actual|
    actual.class.exists?(actual.id)
  end
end
```

When I change the spec to this:

```
describe 'self.cleanup' do
    let(:old_transaction){FactoryGirl.create(:old_transaction)}

    it 'destroys all transactions more than 30 days' do
      Transaction.cleanup
      expect(old_transaction).not_to exist_in_database
    end
  end
```

the test fails. I also tried manually creating a transaction and assigning it to :old_transaction with let() but that makes the test fail too.

Why is it that it only passes when I use an instance variable in the before(:each) block?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: FAILED OUTPUT**

```
1) Transaction self.cleanup destroys all transactions more than 30 days
     Failure/Error: expect(old_transaction).not_to exist_in_database
       expected #<Transaction id: 2, seller_id: 3, buyer_id: 4, item_id: 2, transaction_date: nil, created_at: "2014-02-26 10:06:30", updated_at: "2014-04-09 10:06:32", buyer_confirmed: false, seller_confirmed: false, cancelled: false> not to exist in database
     # ./spec/models/transaction_spec.rb:40:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`let` is lazy loaded. So in your failing spec this is the order of events:

1. `Transaction.cleanup`
2. `old_transaction = FactoryGirl.create(:old_transaction)`
3. `expect(old_transaction).not_to exist_in_database`

So the transaction is created **after** you attempt to clean up.

There are multiple options for you:

#### Don't use `let` for this

Unless you have other specs that you want to tell other devs:

> I fully intend for all of these specs to reference what should be the exact same object

I personally feel, that you're better off inlining the transaction.

```
it do
  transaction = FactoryGirl.create(:old_transaction)

  Transaction.cleanup

  expect(transaction).not_to exist_in_database
end
```

#### Use the `change` matcher

This is my personal choice as it clearly demonstrates the intended behavior:

```
it do
  expect{
    Transaction.cleanup
  }.to change{ Transaction.exists?(old_transaction.id) }.to false
end
```

This works with `let` as the `change` block is run before AND after the `expect` block. So on the first pass the `old_transaction` is instantiated so it's `id` can be checked.

#### Use `before` or reference `old_transaction` before your cleanup

IMO this seems odd:

```
before do
  old_transaction
end

it do
  old_transaction # if you don't use the before
  Transaction.clean
  # ...
end
```

#### Use `let!`

The `let!` is not lazy loaded. Essentially, it's an alias for doing a normal `let`, then calling it in a `before`. I'm not a fan of this method (see [The bang is for surprise](http://aaronkromer.com/blog/2013-05-19-the-bang-is-for-surprise.html) for details why).

Comment: I went with the first option. Though I think I might consider the second if my custom matcher fails me anytime.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've just accidentally typoed in a ":"

Try this spec:

```
describe 'self.cleanup' do
  let(:old_transaction){FactoryGirl.create(:old_transaction)}
  it 'destroys all transactions more than 30 days' do
    Transaction.cleanup
    expect(old_transaction).not_to exist_in_database
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately this still doesn't work. I'll go ahead and edit the question to fix the typo so other answers can look at it the other way

Comment: sorry, @gernberg, that doesn't seem to be the issue as well. I am not using any save on any spec that is using the old_transaction factory.

Comment: What output do you get from the tests?